# is this class thread safe for different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

This is the class:

```
public class Saver {

    private static ArrayList<String> nameCache = new ArrayList<>();

    public static synchronized void add(ArrayList<String> names) {
        nameCache.addAll(names);
    }

    public static synchronized void save() {
        for (String name : nameCache) {
            //write name
        }
        nameCache.clear();
    }
}
```

Different threads are going to call save and add in different orders.
But will this synchronized keyword make this process thread safe?

And is this the right way to fix concurrency problems, if not what would be a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. You make the class you want to protect thread safe by adding monitors (or other mechanisms) and the threads that will use that class won't be able to use it all together.

Comment: You could potentially get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if another thread modifies `names` while your `addAll` is executing. I also wonder if there is potentially a visibility issue because `nameCache` is not declared `final`.

Comment: @AndyTurner But nameCache is private?

Comment: @user2997204 sorry, that's visibility in the sense of the Java Memory Model, not as in `public`, `private` etc.

Comment: @jameslarge ah, yeah, I suppose so. Cheerfully withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is threadsafe in that you won't have threads stepping on each other. Synchronizing on the class-level lock guarantees that only one thread will have access to the list at a time, and changes by any one thread will be visible to all of the other threads, so [hahn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509415/217324) is correct (+1 from me). But with respect to the question

> is this the right way to fix concurrency problems, if not what would be a good way to solve this problem

the answer is, "it depends on the context, but in general no."

Every thread has to wait for the same lock, and when the list gets saved every thread that wants to add something has to wait. This may create an unacceptable performance issue depending on load and how often the list gets saved.

The solution depends on the circumstances, but in general try to minimize the time needed for the saving method to hold the lock. You might have the saving method make a copy of the list, holding the lock only long enough to make the copy, then save the copy of the list so that other threads could call the add method at the same time that the copy is getting saved.

Caching is something that tends to be more fraught with peril than you think it will be (am I saving outdated items? when does the cache need to expire? am I creating a memory leak? etc.), also it is a technical implementation detail that tends to get mixed in with business logic, which makes the code uglier and harder to follow. Making the data and methods static introduces global state into the application that may make testing hard, making the data and methods belong to the object instance instead and injecting it where you want it using dependency injection may be preferable.

Comment: Really nice explanation! But "every thread that wants to add something has to wait", the accessing threads cannot add and remove list items at the same time, right? That's why I synchronized both methods

Comment: @user2997204: right, that's why I started with "hanh's answer is correct." upvoted.

Comment: Alright, anyways thanks for the advice to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

as synchronization is done on `Saver` class, only one `Thread` at a time would have access to `nameCache`.